# Heroku SSL limited cipher suite support on Common Runtime with Custom Domain

Tags: ssl, heroku, encryption, openssl

We recently hit a problem with a third party's backoffice systems connecting to our Heroku common runtime hosted app, because there were no supported cipher suites in common between Heroku and their servers.

Investigation with [this](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest) showed that our custom end point only supports:

- TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
- TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
- TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
- TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
- TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
- TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
- TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
- TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384

How do we expand the list of cipher suites supported so the third party's system can connect with SSL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#available-cipher-suites-on-the-common-runtime) Heroku support article confirmed the cipher suites available on common runtime custom domains.

However, we noted that a wider range of ciphers is available on the default domain.

We changed the URL we were sending to the third party from our custom domain to the default domain for the same application, and a mutually supported cipher was then available.